# Javascript sorting array twice (different sort methods)

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array that at page load sorts the array how I want, depending on the current date it shows the objects that have a future date and then shows the objects with past dates, lets call this datesToPlay.

I have two radio buttons to call on the method to sort the same array, and at page load it sorts the array perfectly fine how I mentioned above. The problem is when I sort the array with the other sorting method, createdAt which simply sorts the array by the date of creation. This method sorts it fine, but when I press the other radio to sort by datesToPlay it doesn't sorts the array.

```
function SortByPlayTime(a, b){
var currentDate = new Date();
    if(lastDateOfObjectsInArray > currentDate){
        if(a.attributes.start >= currentDate){
            if(a.attributes.start > b.attributes.start && b.attributes.start >= currentDate)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
        } else if(b.attributes.start >= currentDate){
            if(b.attributes.start > a.attributes.start)
                return -1;
          else
                return 1;
     }
    else{
        if(a.attributes.start > b.attributes.start)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
} else{
    if(a.attributes.start > b.attributes.start)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}


function SortByCreation(a, b){
if(a.attributes.createdAt > b.attributes.createdAt)
    return 1;
else
    return -1;
```

Basically what Im doing is I have an array with all the objects im trying to sort, this array varies in size and can be like 1000 or more objects.

In function loadArrayToShowFilters() what Im doing is to prepare a new array that will be shown in a table (see comments above for screens). This is cause Im mimicking a table but actually Im doing all the work with arrays; this array will always be 100 length or less.

```
function loadArrayToShowFilters() {
//array = the array of objects Im trying to filter
var sizeArrayToShow;
if(array.length < 100)
    sizeArrayToShow = array.length;
else
    sizeArrayToShow = 100;
arrayTableToShow = [];
//arrayTableToShow = This is the array that holds the objects that are shown on the table
for (var i = 0; i < sizeArrayToShow; i++) {
    arrayTableToShow[i] = array[i];
};
```

Events that trigger the sorts: event click on two radio buttons.

Code that performs the actual sort: on the event click of each radio button, I just do array.sort(SortByCreation) and like so respectively.

Sample data: {"start":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2018-02-01T11:00:00.000Z"},"end":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2018-02-01T12:00:00.000Z"},"createdAt":"2018-01-29T20:37:51.477Z","updatedAt":"2018-02-23T03:12:15.968Z","objectId":"dSVZXFAIyf"}

It's basically just an array with objects, each object with a variable attributes with includes variables start and createdAt which are used to do the sorting

Events:

```
'click #lastCreated'(event){
    orderArregloCreatedAt();
},
'click #nextToPlay'(event){
    orderArregloPlayTime();
}

function orderArregloCreatedAt() {
    array.sort(SortByCreation);
   loadArrayToShowFilters();
}

function orderArregloPlayTime() {
    array.sort(SortByPlayTime);
    loadArrayToShowFilters();
}
```

Comment: Does datesToPlay ==  SortByPlayTime?

Comment: yes sorry I didn't made it clear

Comment: So if I'm following your description:  both sort functions work correctly, but only on page load, not when the  user clicks the radio button to switch sort method.   Is that correct?    If so, can you please include the code where you redraw the DOM after the array is re-sorted?

Comment: Code is missing that performs the actual sort, the sample data that needs to be sorted, the events that trigger the sorts, the output and how it differs from desired output.

Comment: @DanielBeck yes you're correct, Im gonna place the code as answer for clarity but beware it may be confusing I'll try to explain it clearly.

Comment: @trincot Im gonna place the code as an answer below, and here is a link to see how the output differes, the name of the file says what the screen is. Link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8bj7z0nuxxtyb4i/AABHjWXUGuVIyqypZO1nDzu8a?dl=0

Comment: Why not *edit* your question and add the necessary information there? Don't misuse the answer area for providing more information.

Comment: @trincot done updating the question

Comment: The radiobuttons and triggering of the sort should be included as code also. The material to *reproduce* the issue should be in the question.

Comment: @trincot finished updating

Comment: Its on meteor framework btw

Comment: That all looks good to me. Well, not good, but it looks like it could work. Does your radio button control actually have the id "nextToPlay"?

Comment: None of the code you've shown draws anything to the DOM.   Are you under the impression that sorting the array would automatically make changes in the page?

Comment: (I just noticed your comment that you're using Meteor, which I'm not familiar with; perhaps that binds the data to the DOM?  But as far as I can tell you're just creating a new array `arrayTableToShow`, sorting it, and then doing nothing with it...)

Comment: @DanielBeck I just removed the line from the code that does that on meteor, which is reservacionesDepen.changed() (a dependency); I know that the array isn't sort because I have printed the array after every sort, and the array never orders like the first time the page is loaded

Comment: @Raith yes, I mean I can see every time I click a radio the changes on the table, the thing is that when I try to sort it by SortByPlayTime it only sorts it right the first time after the page loads, when I click radio #lastCreated it again orders it correctly, but when I click radio #nextToPlay (which sorts it fine after page load) fails and orders the array in a different way then after page load

Comment: @DaríoVillalta you say that "[it] fails and orders the array in a different way then after page load". So it *is* firing, and it *is* ordering it differently to the previous `SortByCreation`, but *not* the same as the initial `SortByPlayTime`? Are you saying that it gives you a 3rd variation on sorting? 
`SortByPlayTime` does have additional external dependency... is the `lastDateOfObjectsInArray` variable being changed in the meantime as that would affect your sorting logic.

Comment: @Raith so to answer your first part of the question "Are you saying that it gives you a 3rd variation on sorting?" YES, it gives a different new order that doesn't seem to follow any logic unlike after the first time the page loads. "is the lastDateOfObjectsInArray variable being changed in the meantime as that would affect your sorting logic" it can change but for the testing I'm doing now it doesn't, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @DaríoVillalta What is `lastDateOfObjectsInArray` set to, and when? It seems that the entire first half of your `SortByPlayTime` always ends up comparing a.start against b.start irrespective of the conditions checking against currentDate. But the outermost `else` sorts in the opposite order. Are you setting `lastDateOfObjectsInArray` such that the first and second calls to this would compare differently to `currentDate`?

Comment: @DaríoVillalta There is a case in your sort where it would swap places of equal values if applied twice in succession, but your screenshots suggest there are not many equal start dates, so I don't think that's likely to be an issue. However, it might be that your sort is somewhat sensitive to the starting order, which is why it is different after being sorted in the meantime. I don't really believe this though, due to the difference between the data in your screenshots.

Comment: My brain is fading and it is late here. The only way I am going to be able to assist more helpfully is if I can have access to a working example which behaves as you have described. Any chance of a jsfiddle?

Comment: @DaríoVillalta At the very least, please can you provide the starting order of the data (before your first sort), and the code snippet that sets `lastDateOfObjectsInArray` and enough context to know when it is set. And as an experiment, on your page load, please can you sort your array twice, firstly using `SortByCreation` and *then* by `SortByPlayTime` and tell me if you still think it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information needed to resolve this issue is still sorely lacking from this question. But I think the fault lies in the sorting algorithm of `SortByPlayTime`.

This is a bit of a wild shot, but please can you tell me if the following change delivers:

- expected sort order at page load?
- expected sort order after clicking the radio button?
- the same results for both, even if it's wrong?

Code change:

```
function SortByPlayTime(a, b) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    // a is future, b is past, so a shows above b = -1
    if (a.attributes.start >= currentDate && b.attributes.start < currentDate) return -1;
    // a is past, b is future, so a shows below b = 1
    if (a.attributes.start < currentDate && b.attributes.start >= currentDate) return 1;
    // both a and b are similarly future or past so compare on their values alone, in ascending order
    // if a > b then it should show below b, = positive result
    return a.attributes.start - b.attributes.start;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot kind stranger for taking the patience and your valuable time!  This made it work perfectly, just had to add at the last return: a.attributes.start - b.attributes.start. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: I'm glad this worked. It was hard work poring over incomplete fragments of code. I removed the `lastDateOfObjectsInArray` because I can see no good coming from it - it looks like a magic switch to change the sort order entirely, in which case you should write another sort function. Apologies for the last line mistake, I was writing from my head and oversimplified it! I've amended my answer to match. Please thank me more by up-voting my answer as I would appreciate the reputation boost! And you are welcome :)

Comment: I've tried but due to my reputation it doesn't shows but stack overflow shows me a message that they take it in consideration: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Thanks a bunch m8!